# While adding the class library I am getting an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi, class-library

I have created a **C# web application project** and added one new project "Class Library. In the class library, I am trying to add "**ADO.NET Entity Data Model**" but I am getting below snap error.

[image]

What is reason behind it. I am using visual studio 2019.

Comment: Try adding EntityFramework v 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On which .Net Version did you create your web application project?

You need to create your project on a .Net version that is compatible to your added lib.

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.8.